# Accessing Type properties of Func<Type>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, nhibernate

I'm starting to get my hands dirty with delegates but I'm stuck badly with the below mentioned issue. Can anyone tell me how I access Type properties of a `Func<Type>`?

I'm explaining my scenario below:

This is the class where I want to access a particular property of `Func<DatabaseSession>` namely `Session` and pass it to the called method:

```
namespace MyApp.WebApplication{
  public class MvcApplication{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters, Func<DatabaseSession> databaseSession){
        filters.Add(new MyAppPerformanceFilter(LocalEnvironment, databaseSession)) // here I want to pass databaseSession.Session
        // lines of code
    }
  }
}
```

This is the `DatabaseSession` class, whose `Session` property I need to access:

```
namespace A{
    public sealed class DatabaseSession 
    {
    public ISession Session { get; private set; } // where ISession resides in the 'NHibernate' namespace
    // lines of code
    }   
}
```

**Note:** the `databaseSession` object looks like this and I can't find my required `Session` property inside it:
[image]

Below is the receiver class where I want to access the `Session` property. Note that, I have specified the argument type as `object` and not `Func<DatabaseSession>` or `DatabaseSession` because the reference of `namespace A` can't be added to this project because of cyclic dependency:

```
namespace B{
     public class MyAppPerformanceFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
     {
        private ISession Session { get; set; } // where ISession resides in the 'NHibernate' namespace

        public MyAppPerformanceFilter (object obj)
        {
           Session  = obj; // retrieve the value here
        }
        
        // lines of code
     }
}
```

Comment: You could change it to: `new MyAppPerformanceFilter(LocalEnvironment, databaseSession()?.Session)` ? As it is `Func<T>` it holds a function that returns instance of `T` so in order to get this `T` you'd need to call the function first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delegates (like `Func<T>`) are what other programming languages refer to as function pointers. The are basically a way to store a method in a variable to call at a later point. The delegate simply describes what the method must look like. In case of `Func<T>` it means a method that has no parameters and returns type `T`.

Here's some dumb sample code for clarification:

```cs
static class Maths
{
  public static int Add(int a, int b) => a + b;
  public static int Sub(int a, int b) => a - b;
  public static int Mul(int a, int b) => a * b;

  public static int DoMath(int a, int b, Func<int, int, int> func)
  {
    return func(a,b);
  }
}

class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    int res = Maths.DoMath(2, 3, Maths.Mul);
  }
}
```

Note that, when calling `Maths.DoMath` I pass `Maths.Mul` as the third argument without calling it or anything. That's because I don't want to invoke the method here but pass the method itself along to DoMaths.

Back to your problem, you can't extract `Session` from `databaseSession` because the later is just a function that, upon invoking, will return a `DatabaseSession` object. So your code could be adjusted like so:

```cs
  public class MvcApplication{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters, Func<DatabaseSession> databaseSession){
        var dbSession = databaseSession(); //invoke passed method.
        filters.Add(new MyAppPerformanceFilter(LocalEnvironment, dbSession.Session))
        // lines of code
    }
  }
```

Of course, all this makes using delegates a bit of a mood point if you just invoke them in the constructor right away.